# RewriteRule with multiple params?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a URL Rewrite by converting

```
http://domain.com/sitemap.php?category=car&month=10&date=30
```

to

```
http://domain.com/sitemap-car-10-30.xml
```

I tried the following RewriteRule  :

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap.php?category=$1&month=$2&date=&3   [L]
```

I couldn't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? and how can I make it work?

Thanks !

Comment: Rule looks fine, what doesn't work? Do you have other rules also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `[QSA]` flag at the end of your rewrite. QSA stands for Query String Append. You also had a typo at the end of your rewrite, where you wrote `&3` instead of `$3`:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap.php?category=$1&month=$2&date=$3   [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, use [QSA] when you rewrite with query string from the original URL, not in this case.